# What test classes does `mvn test` execute?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I am using Cucumber, Java - Maven. I have class named `TestRunner` anotated with `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` which is executed in command `mvn test`. But it also execute all jUnit methods marked with tag `@Test` (for some basic stuff i have this kind of methods). When i change class `TestRunner` to `XxxRunner`. It wont be executed. I spend whole morning finding out what is executed with command `mvn test` and what jUnit starts. Can somebody make it more clear to me, and is it really important to name class with text `Test` in it? 
//version of jUnit: `4.13-beta-2`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: One God damn sentence. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This one: "By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:". I was searching for whole day.